# How to get the maxium row value for a similar values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, greatest-n-per-group

In my table below, I have `id` and `job_id` fields with some of the `job_id` fields being duplicates.
I want to get the `MAXIMUM` value of the `id` field corresponding to each  `unique` `job_id`.

I have now tried the `GROUP_BY` clause, but it is not giving me the right result.

For instance,

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id, job_id
FROM job_status_update
GROUP BY job_id
```

would produce:

[image]

But from the first image, the `id` of **6** from the job_status_update table corresponds to `job_status_id` of **3** and not **1**
So I want to write a query to get just these fields:
`max_id`, `job_id`

Please can someone give me a pointer on what to do?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: That query does not include `job_status_id`; fix it.

Comment: You need some technique involving "groupwise-max"; it cannot be done in a query as simple as what you have.

Comment: I see you've updated your question now. Originally you were not asking for the `job_status_id` to be returned (as your question still says "*I want to write a query to get **just** these fields: max_id, job_id*'). I'll update my query when I get a chance to return the *correct* `job_status_id` for your **latest row** per grouping. To get the latest row you can use a window function, and the query becomes a little more complicated, but is definitely doable. Please update your post's tags with which version and implementation of MySQL you're using, as that will affect the answer now as well.

Comment: @ErnestElikem Please see my updated answer, with an updated dbfiddle, demonstrating how to achieve what you're actually looking for. Please note you must be on at least MySQL version 8.0 to utilize this solution (please updated your post's tags with which version of MySQL you're on, as I previously requested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you really wanted the whole row (or at least other fields of the row itself) besides the max `id` per `job_id`, you can accomplish this with a window function like [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) like so:

```
-- only latest row per job_id
SELECT id AS max_id, job_id, job_status_id --, updated_by, date_added, last_updated
FROM
(
  SELECT id, job_id, job_status_id, updated_by, date_added, last_updated,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS GroupSortId
  FROM job_status_update
) Results
WHERE GroupSortId = 1 -- returns only the latest row per grouping of job_id
```

This will group up all duplicate `job_id`s and return only the max row of each grouping, thus resulting in a distinct result set of `job_id`s, their correlating `max_id` and the *correct* correlating `job_status_id`. If you want the other fields as well, please remove the comment in the outer-query's `SELECT` list.

Please see [this dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mPKATChZVPG1vCMHmYtGMd/12) for a working example.

Comment: It did not work. Please using the group by clause still results in not getting the actual `max_id` value. It simply returns the first row that from the group by clause. I am trying to do a sorting first and then do a grouping and see if it would work.

Comment: @ErnestElikem Please update your question with the exact query you're using, the results you're getting, and your expected results. Based on what you described my above query should get what you're looking for.

Comment: @ErnestElikem Also please see the working example with my query that I just linked at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Your query works fine. But there is a possibility that the jobs are not updated in the same order that you have demonstrated in your DB-Fiddle.

The problem is with the group by clause. Even though it prevents duplicates, it results in getting only the first `job_status_id` that was obtained from the `GROUP BY` clause.

So though what you have presented is good, in the real-world (at least for my application), things would not work that way.

Comment: @ErnestElikem I've updated the dbfiddle to insert the jobs data in a different order to show that it doesn't matter what order the data is inserted into the table, you still get the same results. Please re-open and re-run the dbfiddle to see that. If you want to re-order the results **after** getting the `max_id` then please let me know with more details on how you want the results to be ordered, but the data of the results themselves is correct (regardless of how and when your data is inserted / updated in your table). It always returns the max id. This is true for your application as well.